# Two step Backward differentiation formula

Tags: numerical-methods

Derive the two step BDF method, the final solution should be $$y_n = \frac{4}{3}y_{n-1} - \frac{1}{3}y_{n-2} + \frac{2}{3}h f_n$$ I am pretty sure we can use backward euler to derive it i.e. $$y_n - y_{n-1} = hf_n$$ but I have no idea how to do this, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By taking Taylor Series', we can write
$$ y_n=y_{n-1}+hf_n+\frac{h^2}{2}f'_n+O(h^3) $$
and 
$$ y_n=y_{n-2}+2hf_n+2h^2f''_n+O(h^3). $$

Now take a combination of these two expressions to give a new expression for $y_n$,
$$ y_n=a\Big(y_{n-1}+hf_n+\frac{h^2}{2}f'_n\Big)+b\Big(y_{n-2}+2hf_n+2h^2f'_n\Big)+O(h^3), $$
and we require $a+b=1$. Simplifying,
$$ y_n=ay_{n-1}+by_{n-2}+(a+2b)hf_n+(a+4b)\frac{h^2}{2}f'_n+O(h^3). $$
We can choose $a$ to maximise the convergence of this formula (since $b=1-a$). We do this by setting $O(h^2)$ term to $0$, by having $a+4b=0$, which gives $a=-4b$. Thus, $a=4/3$ and $b=-1/3$, and our BDF is
$$ y_n=\frac{4}{3}y_{n-1}-\frac{1}{3}y_{n-2}+\frac{2}{3}hf_n. $$